# Stop an audio file playing in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have music playing and I want it to stop when I get to the game over routine.
I initialize it in the body:

```
<audio id="music" src="sw_music.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

and try to stop it here:

```
case 25://You're dead
    document.getElementById("audio"); 
    audio.pause();
```

I tried using the audio stop in a function but it did not stop.

I also use a laser blast audio component:

```
<audio id="laser" src="Laser.mp3"></audio>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("audio")` doesn’t do anything and `audio` is not defined. Check your console for errors.

Comment: yes I did that and you're correct, that's the error I get. My post did not show the code as i intended it. I put the spaces in but to no avail. I apologize I'm new to the posting/forum.    <audio id="laser" src="Laser.mp3"></audio>
I have that line which I thought was defining the audio. It plays fine, just doesn't stop

Comment: `var audio = document.getElementById('yourAudioElementId'), button = document.getElementById('someInputTypeButtonId'); audio.play(); button.onclick = function(){ audio.pause(); }`.

Comment: Ok Ill try that. Perhaps because I have 2 audio elements?? The one above  does a laser blast which I dont need to stop due to its length. I have another file playing theme music in background.

Comment: @Drumbo1969 You just need to find the `HTMLAudioElement` that you need, then call its `pause` method. There’s no button involved, as PHPglue is suggesting.

Comment: Currently, you’re just finding that element, but not doing anything with it, then calling `pause` on an undefined variable.

Comment: as shown: `//You're dead document.getElementById("audio"); audio.pause();` that whole line is a comment - how about posting the code properly formatted - but as pointed out you're using a variable called `audio` which is seemingly never initialised in the cast amount of code you posted

Comment: @JaromandaX When clicking [edit], it’s multiple lines. The OP just doesn’t know how to [format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/289905).

Comment: I know that, you know that, I did suggest properly formatted code in my comment :p

Comment: JaromandaX I apologize as I said. I'm new to this. When I copy and pasted code it didn't upload as it showed. The comment is just on "//You're dead". The next line is where I tried stopping. I think my problem may be I have 2 audio files within 2 <audio> tags. Perhaps I confusing the compiler.

Comment: Code formatted. Thanks Jaromanda X

Comment: @Drumbo1969 There is no compiler to be confused, and no, having multiple `<audio>` elements is fine. Have you tried `document.getElementById("audio").pause();` already?

Comment: Xufox thanks. that worked but after executing the game it not really necessary to stop music since the player restarts and plays again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at the comments:

> var music = document.getElementById("music");
>
> music.pause();